# What is a Polariton and why are they useful in unconventional computing?

Tags: quantum-computer

My lecturer has frequently mentioned the term *polariton* and a quick search on the Internet lead me to its Wikipedia page (which is not surprising but the page is not particularly helpful) as well as a few popular-science style articles (such as [this one](https://www.cam.ac.uk/research/news/new-type-of-supercomputer-could-be-based-on-magic-dust-combination-of-light-and-matter) and [this one](https://www.vice.com/en_us/article/8x85vk/physicists-imagine-a-supercomputer-based-on-magic-dust?utm_campaign=sharebutton)).

My question is what exactly are polarities and the *bigger* question is why are they useful (or equivalently why are they *used* among so many other things) in unconventional/quantum computing?